# Parse Rarzor Html Helper from externally stored .cshtml

Tags: razor

On my site I have quite a few content pages. Most of them a purely text but some do contain links and similar stuff.
I'm using wordpress as my backend-cms where I store the body of the pages and using webrequests I load the content of a post into a generic ContentModel:

```
public class WordPressPostModel
{
    public string Title;
    public string Content;
    public string postId;
    public string slug;
    public string lang;
    public string CategorySlug;
    public DateTime CacheDate = new DateTime();
    public bool NotFound = true;

    public WordPressPostModel()
    {

    }
}
```

What would be fantastic is if I could treat the content I get back as a (partial) cshtml view and get ActionLinks and other Html Helpers rendered. Is there a way to do this?

**SOLUTION** using the RazorEngine as Darin suggested:

As the Razor engine does not support the html helpers you will have to work around this by calling them from inside a custom template base e.g.

```
public abstract class MyCustomTemplateBase<T> : TemplateBase<T>
{

    public string ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        string link = HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext, RouteTable.Routes, linkText, "Default", actionName, controllerName, null, null);
        return link;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
    Razor.SetTemplateBase(typeof(MyCustomTemplateBase<>));
    string raw = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Content);        
    string result = Razor.Parse(raw, this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/).